# Implementing Stripe on Nuxt App - StripeCheckout not found in 'vue-stripe-checkout'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments, nuxt.js

I'm trying to implement stripe on my NuxtJS App but I'm facing this error :
StripeCheckout not found in 'vue-stripe-checkout'.
I was trying to follow along this tuto :
https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout#demo

Here is what I did so far :

- Install vue-stripe-checkout package
- Declare plugin in my Nuxt.config.js

```js
plugins: [
  { src: "~/plugins/stripeCheckOut.js", ssr: false }

build: {
  extend(config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        options: {
          fix: true
        }
      });
    },
    transpile: ["/plugins"]
  }
};
```

- Create a plugin

```js
   

 import Vue from 'vue'
    import VueStripeCheckout from 'vue-stripe-checkout'

    const options = {
      key:
        'MY KEY', // STRIPE_TOKEN,
      locale: 'auto',
      currency: 'EUR'
    }

    Vue.use(VueStripeCheckout, options)
```

And finaly call this new plugin in my component :

```js
   

 <template>
      <div>
        <h1>Voici un récapitulatif de votre commande:</h1>
        <stripe-checkout
          ref="checkoutRef"
          :pk="publishableKey"
          :items="items"
          :success-url="successUrl"
          :cancel-url="cancelUrl"
        >
          <template slot="checkout-button">
            <button @click="checkout">
              Shut up and take my money!
            </button>
          </template>
        </stripe-checkout>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
       import { StripeCheckout } from 'vue-stripe-checkout'
       export default {
          name: 'RecapPrice',
          components: {
           StripeCheckout
           },
          data: () => ({
           loading: false,
           publishableKey: process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
           items: [
              {
                sku: 'sku_FdQKocNoVzznpJ',
                quantity: 1
               }
             ],
           successUrl: 'your-success-url',
           cancelUrl: 'your-cancel-url'
      }),
      methods: {
        checkout () {
          console.log('coucou')
          this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout()
        }
      }
    }
 </script>
```

If someone as already implemented Stripe in a Nuxt App, I'd get very happy to get some of your insights

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're likely missing the step that tells Nuxt to transpile the files in plugins directory. I would recommend referencing this thread in the `vue-stripe-checkout` repository which has some solutions to a similar problem: https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout/issues/14#issuecomment-424090505

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
I thought I did with the transpile. I used this github issue to build my code but it doesn't seem to work. Or I might do something wrong. but can't really tell what